# Обход Flood Wait caused by "contacts.ResolveUsername"

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, pyrogram

Использую метод contacts.ResolveUsername для фильтрации списка телеграм - никнеймов, спустя где-то 200 запросов получаю Flood Wait на +- 2.5 часа. Есть ли какие-то способы обойти это?
Из идей было подмешивание иных запросов, дабы это не выглядело, как спам одним и тем же: раз в 5 целевых запросов добавлял отправку сообщения\редактирование сообщения\удаление сообщения, не помогло. Может быть у кого-то есть опыт обхода таким способом? Какие именно запросы используются?
Также есть вариант использовать несколько аккаунтов и переключаться между ними, когда на одном получен Flood Wait, но это на крайний случай, хотелось бы попробовать как-то обойти это или хотя бы отсрочить (200 запросов - довольно мало) без танцев с бубном.
Заранее извиняюсь за возможные неточности в терминах, не сильно прошарен.